# Getting the first and last days of a multi-day event - Solspace Calendar

Tags: craft3, plugin-solspacecalendar, calendar, plugin-calendar

Is there a way to get the first and last days of a multi-day event? I want to be able to style the first and last days differently. I don't see anything like this in the docs.

This is in Craft 3 and Calendar 2.0.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the context of `calendar.month`, if you check out the demo templates, we style the beginning and end of multi-day events with the following code:

```
{% if event.multiDay %}
    {% set classes = classes ~ " multi_day" %}
    {% set classes = classes ~ (day.containsDate(event.startDateLocalized) ? " first_day") %}
    {% set classes = classes ~ (day.containsDate(event.endDateLocalized) ? " last_day") %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks - I must've missed that in the demo templates.

Comment: This is almost fully working. The bit that doesn't work is the "first_day" class per your example. Even in the demo templates the class for the first day isn't applied. Any ideas?

Comment: Screenshot of the demo templates in my setup here: https://d.pr/i/a0T1BV

Comment: Perhaps try reinstalling demo templates. Multi-day events appear to display correctly for me...

Comment: Hm, that didn't work.

Comment: I'm going to guess your event is 2 days long? I am looking back at my test site and it appears this works smoothly for events 3 days or longer, but has trouble with the first of 2 days. Checking into that... EDIT, just saw your screenshot shows 3-day event...

Comment: Okay, it seems to only work correctly for multi-day events that are not All Day events. It would seem that this is acting as "intended", according to the docs, but obviously this is an oversight. I have made a note about this and we'll address it in the near future. :)

Comment: Okay cool, thank you!

Comment: I've updated the solution... you'll want to just use `startDateLocalized` and `endDateLocalized` instead. This will work for you right now if you switch it. :)

Comment: Perfect, thanks!